# $GLOBAL associative array getting reset on page redirection

Tags: php, global-variables

I tried the following code to create a superglobal variable using $GLOBALS.

test.php

```
<?php
    $GLOBALS['test']='hello';
    header("location:test3.php");
?>
```

Here is the test3.php

```
<?php
    var_dump($GLOBALS);
    echo $GLOBALS['test'];
?>
```

The output i get is

```
array(5) { ["GLOBALS"]=> *RECURSION* ["_POST"]=> array(0) { } ["_GET"]=> 
array(0) { }["_COOKIE"]=> array(1) {"PHPSESSID"]=>string(26)"oer267anbfrrhtj64lpqrocdd3"} 
["_FILES"]=> array(0) { } }
```

The $GLOBAL['test'] is not getting set.

But when I try var_dump in test.php,I find $GLOBAL array to have a key 'test' with value 'hello'.

What is the reason of this behaviour?

Also I wish to create a superglobal database connection object using the $GLOBAL.Is it recommended?

Comment: No to both. Don't use globals, and you don't need statics / globals for your DB. You'll find plenty of questions that deal with this on SO, just use the search

Comment: Heh, please, before asking, learn at least the basics of the language. You would have soon found out that PHP does not reuse variables between requests.

Comment: I expected all superglobals behave just like $_SESSION[ ]

Comment: [... That's because variables aren't really "global" in PHP.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1557799/345031)

Answer (score 1):

Try using $_SESSION instead of $GLOBALS for setting stateful variables.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 'hello';
header("location:test3.php");

// test3.php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

As far as a $GLOBAL database connection, your best bet is to read about singleton variables related to database connections. I would NOT recommend storing anything in the $GLOBALS array.

Quick google search on database singletons returned several pages, but here is a [decent one](http://www.ricocheting.com/code/php/mysql-database-class-wrapper-v3).

Comment: How can you make $GLOBALS to serve its purpose?

Comment: You don't. You refer to $_POST, $_GET, $_SESSION, etc. Check out the php docs @ http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php